# Rational $d$-simplices

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, rational-points, geometry-of-numbers

Define a *rational $d$-simplex* as a simplex in $\mathbb{R}^d$
such that the measure of all its $k$-dimensional faces, $k \ge 1$, is rational.
So a rational triangle has rational edge lengths and rational area.
A rational tetrahedron has six rational edge lengths, four rational face areas,
and rational volume. And so on. (By scaling these could all be natural numbers.)

> ***Q***. For which $d$ is it known that there are 
>   an infinite number of non-similar rational simplices in $\mathbb{R}^d$ ?

(The non-similar restriction is to exclude scalings.)
This is in some sense a request to update Richard Guy's *Unsolved Problems In Number Theory*, Problem D22. But I am specifically interested in the boundary between an infinite number of examples, and a finite class of distinct examples.
Is that boundary: *Yes* ($\infty$) for $d \le 3$, and *No* (or unknown?) for $d > 3$? Or is the boundary: $d \le 2$ vs. $d > 2$? Or some other divison?

---

[image: HeronianT]

<sup>(Image from [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeronianTetrahedron.html).
Face areas $1170, 1800, 1890, 2016$; volume $18144$.)</sup>

---

***Update***. Answered in the comments by *j.c.* and *Moritz Firsching*:
Infinite families are known up to $d=3$, but not for $d \ge 4$ (and it seems
unlikely even in $d=4$).

Comment: It may be worth linking your previous highly related question http://mathoverflow.net/a/71968 . Also, the paper of Buchholz "Perfect Pyramids" http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0004972700030252 cited by Guy in Problem D22 gives an infinite family of rational 3-simplices, according to the abstract of a more recent paper by Chisholm and MacDougall "Rational and Heron tetrahedra" http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2006.02.009 .

Comment: Buchholz examines 4-dimensional pentahedra and writes: "Since any simplex has 10 edges, 10 faces, 5 volumes and 1 hypervolume, the
occurrence of a perfect 4-pyramid, which requires all these quantities to be integral, is probably a rarity at best." It gets worse for higher dimensions. (He goes on to find the n-simplices that have rational edges lenght and rational (full-dimensional) volume.